# Looking for Camion - Abelian codes

Tags: reference-request, it.information-theory, coding-theory

I am looking for a copy of the old report "Paul Camion - Abelian codes", Technical Report 1059, University of Wisconsin 1971. I have asked Paul himself, but he could not help me. Anyone out there has an electronic copy? 
Henk D.L. Hollmann (henk.hollmann at ntu.edu.sg)

Comment: Web search immediately found it: * http://www.stat.ncsu.edu/information/library/mimeo.archive/ISMS_1970_600.32.pdf

Comment: That is great, thanks a lot! I also tried a search of course, but could not locate anything. Would you like to share how you did your search?

Comment: Unfortunately, now I look at the document, I see that it is not the 60+ pages 1971 Wisconsin University report that I am looking for, but instead a nine-page report from University of North Carolina, 1969. So the request still stands...

Comment: I checked out IEEEXplore in case it had been at least partly included in some conference proceedings or something (most likely you already checked that out as well), but apparently their database only extends back to 1983. What a rip off :-)